Bivariate data generation
Consider the distribution with the bivariate cumulative distribution function $$F(t_1,t_2)=t_1^{1+\theta\log(t_2)}t_2,0<t_1,t_2<1; \theta\leq 0$$.
I want to generate data from this distribution (using R-programming). I know how to generate data in the univariate case but I have no idea for the bivariate case.

A first step might be to look at the marginal distribution of $T_1$, i.e. $\mathbb P(T_1 \le t_1)$, and use this to generate values of $T_1$. For each one of these, you can then generate corresponding values of $T_2$ using univariate methods.

A first remark about this distribution is that both marginals are Uniform $\mathcal U(0,1)$ since $F(t_1,1)=t_1\mathbb{I}_{(0,1)}(t_1)$ and $F(1,t_2)=t_2\mathbb{I}_{(0,1)}(t_2)$. The distribution is therefore a copula.
If one considers the change of variables
$$X_1=-\ln T_1\quad\text{and}\quad X_2=-\ln T_2$$
$X_1$ and $X_1$ are standard Exponential random variables, with complement-cdf
$$G(x_1,x_2)=\int_{x_1}^\infty \int_{x_2}^\infty g(y_1,y_2)\,\text dy_1\text dy_2 =\exp\{-x_1-x_2+\theta x_1 x_2\}\qquad x_1,x_2>0$$
The corresponding density is obtained by differentiating twice
$$
g(x_1,x_2) = \dfrac{\text{d}^2}{\text dx_1\text dx_2} G(x_1,x_2)=
\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text dx_1} ([-1+\theta x_1]\exp\{-x_1-x_2+\theta x_1 x_2\})\\
\qquad=\theta\exp\{-x_1-x_2+\theta x_1 x_2\}+[-1+\theta x_1][-1+\theta x_2]\exp\{-x_1-x_2+\theta x_1 x_2\}\\
=[\theta+1-\theta x_1-\theta x_2+\theta^2x_1x_2]\exp\{-x_1-x_2+\theta x_1 x_2\}\qquad\qquad\quad
$$
which shows that, necessarily
$$-1\le \theta\le 0$$
and from which one can derive the conditional density of $X_1$ given $X_2$ and hence simulate from this conditional distribution, which happens to be a mixture of two Gamma distributions, $\mathcal G(1,1-\theta x_1)$ and $\mathcal G(2,1-\theta x_1)$
$$\require{cancel}\frac{\theta+1-\theta x_1}{\cancel{1-\theta x_1}}\cancel{\exp\{-x_1\}}\overbrace{[1-\theta x_1]\exp\{-(1-\theta x_1) x_2\}}^{\mathcal G(1,1-\theta x_1)}-\theta\frac{1-\theta x_1}{[1-\theta x_1]^\cancel{2}} \cancel{\exp\{-x_1\}}\underbrace{[1-\theta x_1]^2x_2\exp\{-(1-\theta x_1) x_2\}}_{\mathcal G(2,1-\theta x_1)}$$

Can you give me explicit form? Actually I don't understand what does regular mixture mean.
